# The scanf keeps being skipped

Tags: c, scanf

After I formatted the "direccion"'s scanf in function "leerdatos", it skip the "nro_corredor" in the second 'for' loop.

I've already read the related questions but still not getting an answer.

What can I do to solve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int minutos;
    int segundos;
} s_tiempo;

typedef struct {
        int nro_corredor;   // guarda nro de corredor
        s_tiempo tiempo;      // guarda el tiempo que tardo el corredor
} carrera;

typedef struct {
        int nro_corredor;  // guarda nro de corredor
        char apellido[20];
        char nombres[20];
        char direccion[30];
} datos;

datos leerdatos(); //declaro la funcion leer

int main (void) {
    int cp; //cantidad de participantes.
    datos aux;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de participantes: ");
    scanf("%d",&cp);
    datos corredor[cp];
    carrera carreras[cp];
    printf("A continuacion, ingrese los datos de los corredores: \n");
    for(int i=0;i<cp;i++){
        aux = leerdatos();
        corredor[i] = aux;
    }
}

datos leerdatos(void) {
    datos participante;
    printf("\nIngrese el numero de corredor: ");
    scanf("%d",&participante.nro_corredor);
    printf("\nIngrese el apellido:\n");
    scanf("%s",participante.apellido);
    printf("\nIngrese los nombres:\n");
    scanf("%s",participante.nombres);
    printf("\nIngrese la direccion:\n");
    scanf(" %s\n",participante.direccion);
    return(participante);
}
```

Comment: @rayryeng: no, in C that's fine (C99 and later) - you may be thinking of C++ ?

Comment: I don't think this would compile as C++, so it's probably safe to assume it's plain C. OP needs to fix his tags though.

Comment: Sorry for no specify, my bad

Comment: *it skip the "nro_corredor" in the second 'for' loop.* -- How did you determine this?

Comment: You just need to fix your scanf format strings.

Comment: But how? I'd apreciate it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I while ago I tested it, but now the IDE doesn't compile it at all.

Comment: @AntúVillegas Okay, so you tested it. And then you determined that "*it skip the "nro_corredor" in the second 'for' loop*". **How?** What specific evidence did you gather and how did you draw that conclusion from it?

Comment: if you put a leading space in ALL your scanf() format strings, then leading white space, such as '\n' will be consumed, so all the scanf() will work.  However, it is necessary to test each scanf() return code to assure that the variable was actually set.  So for instance, this: scanf("%d",&participante.nro_corredor);
    printf("\nIngrese el apellido:\n"); should be: if( 1 == scanf("%d",&participante.nro_corredor) ) {
    printf("\nIngrese el apellido:\n"); } else { // handle error condition }

Comment: this line: aux = leerdatos(); should be leerdatos( &aux ); and change the leerdatos() to match the new parameter setup.  Otherwise, a (hidden) set of memory will be reserved by the compiler for the return parameter, then memcpy() will be invoked, at least twice, to copy the return parameter/struct to the hidden area then to the actual 'aux' struct.

Comment: @user3629249  "put a leading space in ALL your scanf() format strings, then leading white space, such as '\n' will be consumed" is true but not needed with OP's code.  `scanf("%d",...);` and `scanf("%s",...);` will consume leading white-space with or without the leading space you suggest.  The problem is OP's use of white-space _after_ the `"%s"` as in `scanf(" %s\n",...`.

Comment: @user3629249 The advice to use `leerdatos( &aux );`, does not alter OP's current issues.  "memcpy() will be invoked, at least twice" is not specified by C.  A compiler _may_ effectively do as you suggest, but optimizing compilers are very good and your suggested approach may not improve any performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other issue you are faced with is the need to **flush the input buffer (stdin)** after calling `scanf`. As chux noted, `scanf` does not consume the newline `'\n'` leaving it in the input buffer to be read as the next character. It is always good to flush the input buffer after each use of `scanf`, **especially** when `scanf` is called multiple times. A simple way to flush the input buffer is:

```
int c = 0;                                  /* test int for getchar */
...
scanf("%d",&cp);
do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');     /* flush input buffer */
```

**Note:** `fflushf` does **not** clear characters remaining in `stdin`.

Comment: Flushing the input buffer as described is not _always_ a good idea, but reasonable to do especially if the last specifier was `%s, %d, %f` etc (but not `%[],%c,%n`).  It is very situation dependent.  Note: better to flush with `int c; do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF);` to prevent an infinite loop on EOF or IO error.

Comment: Correct about the `int c;` I generally include that above, but since I copied his code as an example, I missed it. Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect usage of `scanf()`

```
// scanf(" %s\n", ...
scanf("%s", ...
```

A white-space like `'\n'` after the `"%s"` directs `scanf()` to look for white-space until a non-white space follows. That non-white-space is put back into `stdin`.  This likely means OP had to enter 2 <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the 4th input.

Should always check the `scanf()` return value to see if it is as expected.

```
// scanf("%d",&participante.nro_corredor);
if (scanf("%d",&participante.nro_corredor) != 1) Handle_Error();
```

Putting a space before `"%s"` or `"%d"` in `scanf()` make *no* difference.  These specifiers will consume optional white space even without a leading `" "`.

Recommend to use `fgets()` to read user input (which is *evil*) and then parse with `sscanf()`, `strtok()`, `strtol()`, etc.

---

Note: except inside a scanset `"%[...]"`, white-space like `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, and others each perform the *same*:  They consume any number of white-space.  That `'\n'` in `scanf(" %s\n",...` does *not* scan for 1 `'\n'`.  It scans for *any* number of *any* white-space.  It will keep scanning white-space, including multiple <kbd>Enter</kbd>s until EOF or a non-whitespace is entered.  That non-white-space is then put back into `stdin` as the next `char to be read.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct  s_tiempo
{
    int minutos;
    int segundos;
};

struct carrera
{
        int nro_corredor;   // guarda nro de corredor
        struct s_tiempo tiempo;      // guarda el tiempo que tardo el corredor
};

struct datos
{
        int nro_corredor;  // guarda nro de corredor
        char apellido[20];
        char nombres[20];
        char direccion[30];
};

bool leerdatos( struct datos *); //declaro la funcion leer

int main (void)
{
    int cp; //cantidad de participantes.

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de participantes: ");
    if( 1 != scanf(" %d",&cp) )
    {
        perror( "failed getting participantes using scanf()");
        return( 1 );
    }
    // implied else

    struct datos corredor[cp];
    struct carrera carreras[cp]; // should get compiler warning due to this not being used
    printf("A continuacion, ingrese los datos de los corredores: \n");

    for(int i=0;i<cp;i++)
    {
        if( !leerdatos( &corredor[i]) ) { return( 1 ); }
    }

    return( 0 );
}

bool leerdatos(struct datos* participante)
{
    printf("\nIngrese el numero de corredor: ");
    if( 1 != scanf(" %d",&participante.nro_corredor) )
    {
        perror( "failed getting numer de corredor using scanf()");
        return( false );
    }
    // implied else

    printf("\nIngrese el apellido:\n");
    if( 1 != scanf(" %s",participante.apellido) )
    {
        perror( "failed getting apellido using scanf()");
        return( false );
    }
    // implied else

    printf("\nIngrese los nombres:\n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%s",participante.nombres) )
    {
        perror( "failed getting nombres using scanf()");
        return( false );
    }
    // implied else

    printf("\nIngrese la direccion:\n");
    if( 1 != scanf(" %s\n",participante.direccion) )
    {
        perror( "failed getting direccion using scanf()");
        return( false );
    }
    // implied else

    return(true);
}
```

Comment: The white-space before `"%s"` in `" %s\n"` is not needed, but then it does not hurt either.  Same for `" %d"`.  But that `"\n"` in `" %s\n"` is certain to cause OP grief.  Recommend changing to `"%s"`.