# The last scanf() is either skipped or ignored

Tags: c, io, scanf, stdin

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INFTY 1000.0
#define EPS 0.0001
#define XRANGE 2
#define URANGE 2

float absf(float);
float E(float,float,float,float,float,float);

int main(){
    FILE* out;
    float T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP,x,u;
    char filename [45];
    int c;
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("Enter the dimensionless parameters greater or equal to 0:\nT = ");
    scanf("%f",&T);
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');//flush stdin
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("R = ");
    scanf("%f",&R);
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("G = ");
    scanf("%f",&G);
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("alpha = ");
    scanf("%f",&ALPHA);
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("step size (recommended:0.001 to 0.01): ");
    scanf("&f",&STEP);
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    if((T<0)||(R<0)||(G<0)||(ALPHA<0)||(STEP<0)) return 1;//crash if <0
    sprintf(filename,"%.4g_%.4g_%.4g_%.4g_%.5g.dat",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);
    out = fopen(filename,"w");
    fprintf(out,"#T=%.3e R=%.3e G=%.3e alpha=%.3e\n",T,R,G,ALPHA);
    //do the job
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue here is that it seems to completely ignore the last `scanf()` where the step size is supposed to be entered; it just takes whatever junk was in the memory and goes with it, usually a very small number. This output is very characteristic:

```
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 72406190763540480.000000
Enter the dimensionless parameters greater or equal to 0:
T = 1
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 72406190763540480.000000
R = 1
1.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 72406190763540480.000000
G = 1
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000 72406190763540480.000000
alpha = 1.2
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.200000 72406190763540480.000000
step size (recommended:0.001 to 0.01): 0.01
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.200000 72406190763540480.000000
```

As is evident, it's possible to overwrite every variable except the last one. The file is created even before the last `scanf()` is complete. Moving the step size input to the top produces another issue:

```
step size (recommended:0.001 to 0.01): 0.01
Enter the dimensionless parameters greater or equal to 0:
T = R = 1
G = 1
alpha = 1.2
^C
```

In this case, `STEP` wasn't actually overwritten by 0.01, but remained a very small number.
I have looked for similar cases, but there doesn't seem to be any widespread issues like rogue spaces in the input. I'm flushing `stdin` after `scanf()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537541/the-scanf-keeps-being-skipped).

I'm looking forward to any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the return values of all your input function calls? Is any of them different from what you expect? Especially the one previous to what fails.

Comment: Typo: `scanf("&f",&STEP);` -- `&f` should be `%f`.

Comment: Enable full warnings, my compiler complained that the number of data arguments didn't match the number of format operators.

Comment: The `scanf()` function, like many functions, _returns_ a value.  Had this code tested that return value, the error would have quickly been detected.  Like `if (scanf("&f",&STEP) != 1) puts("Error");`

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue! I'll try to take into account your suggestions in the future.

Comment: The newline gobbling loops like `do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');` should take into account EOF: `do { c=getchar(); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);` (assuming you stick with a `do…while` loop), or: `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` (where the semicolon would on a line on its own if it were not in a comment where such formatting is not possible).  Your `scanf()` calls should be tested too: if the result is not `1`, you've got problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have used '&' in place of '%' in  scanf("&f",&STEP);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INFTY 1000.0
#define EPS 0.0001
#define XRANGE 2
#define URANGE 2

float absf(float);
float E(float,float,float,float,float,float);

int main(){
    FILE* out;
    float T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP,x,u;
    char filename [45];
    int c;
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("Enter the dimensionless parameters greater or equal to 0:\nT = ");
    scanf("%f",&T);
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');//flush stdin
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("R = ");
    scanf("%f",&R);
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("G = ");
    scanf("%f",&G);
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("alpha = ");
    scanf("%f",&ALPHA);
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    printf("step size (recommended:0.001 to 0.01): ");
```

> Replace &f with %f, it will work in 
>   scanf("&f",&STEP);

```
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);//debug
    if((T<0)||(R<0)||(G<0)||(ALPHA<0)||(STEP<0)) return 1;//crash if <0
    sprintf(filename,"%.4g_%.4g_%.4g_%.4g_%.5g.dat",T,R,G,ALPHA,STEP);
    out = fopen(filename,"w");
    fprintf(out,"#T=%.3e R=%.3e G=%.3e alpha=%.3e\n",T,R,G,ALPHA);
    //do the job
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```